# How to use values from foreign key tables in asp.net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, charts

I have a DB table with following values (select * from tbl where PRO_ID=2061):
[image]

And I have a asp:Chart. The above table can also be the Chart1.DataSource. Markup could look like this:

```
            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="800px" Height="400px">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Risk HW" ChartArea="ChartArea1" YValueMembers="HW_ID">
```

This works. But HW_ID is a foreign key and I want to have another value from table tbl_HW instead.
Best would be: YValueMembers="tbl_HW.myWantedValue".
Can I call somehow to the parent table and get the wanted value (in an easy way)?

(Hint: I use Entity Framework. Perhaps it can be achieved with EntityDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the objects mapped so that the object which populates that table has the other table's class as a property, you should be able to databind to it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687487/how-to-properly-bind-to-a-child-object) seems to have some relevant info, though not specific to a chart.

The property names in databound controls are reflected onto the objects bound to them, so you can use properties of complex objects (so if you bind an object of type Foo you could have a binding to Foo.bar.Pickle, if the Foo class had a property bar which is an object that has a property named 'Pickle')